# Connection failed: SQLState: '01000' SQL Server Error: 10061

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection

I'm trying to connect my access front-end to the SQL Server backend.

It was working when SQL Server was on my computer but now i'm trying to connect to a server

So when I create the DSN file with access

1. I chose SQL-Server driver ( I have also tried with SQL-Server native 10.0 )
2. I enter the server name that I copied from SQL Management Studio so there's no typo there
3. I chose the NT authentication

Then I have this error

[image]

In the properties, I tried with `TCP/IP` with the default port 1433 and I also tried with the name pipes

I made sure that the checkbox to allow remote connection is checked

If I try to connect with management studio I got this error

[image]

I can see the server when I browse on the network

I'm trying [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/07/19/tcp-provider-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it.aspx) troubleshotting but i'm stuck with the telnet command. It says `Could not open connection to host on 1433`

I also tried with no port and i got the same error on port 23

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: @wOlf I put the access tags cause I'm making the dsn with access

Comment: If you can access SQL Server through Management Studio, check the SQL Server error log. The error you get in Access is obscure by default, but the line item in the error log might reveal more information both in the message text and in the message state. If you get a particular state number you might check this reference: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/01/14/sql-server-v-next-denali-additional-states-for-error-18456.aspx

Comment: Is it possible that I don't see any error?

Comment: Yes, but that would only happen if your connection string is not valid, and SQL Server really could not be located by Access.

Comment: When I try with sql management studio. I can see the server on the network but I got this error. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

### **To create a new Data source to SQL Server, do the following steps:**

1. In host computer/server go to Sql server management studio --> open Security Section on left hand --> right click on Login, select New Login and then create a new account for your database which you want to connect to.
2. Check the TCP/IP Protocol is Enable. go to All programs --> Microsoft SQL server 2008 --> Configuration Tools --> open Sql server configuration manager. On the left hand select client protocols (based on your operating system 32/64 bit). On the right hand, check TCP/IP Protocol be Enabled.
3. In Remote computer/server, open Data source administrator. Control panel --> Administrative tools --> Data sources (ODBC).
4. In User DSN or System DSN , click Add button and select Sql Server driver and then press Finish.
5. Enter Name.
6. Enter Server, note that: if you want to enter host computer address, you should enter that`s IP address without "\\". eg. 192.168.1.5 and press Next.
7. Select With SQL Server authentication using a login ID and password entered by the user.
8. At the bellow enter your login ID and password which you created on first step. and then click Next.
9. If shown Database is your database, click Next and then Finish.

Answer (score 1):

1. Windows firewall blocks the sql server. Even if you open the 1433 port from exceptions, in the client machine it sets the connection point to dynamic port. Add also the sql server to the exceptions.

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\Sqlservr.exe"

[More info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043(v=sql.110).aspx)

2. [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2008/11/07/sql-server-error-10060-sql-server-error-10061/) page helped me to solve the problem. Especially

> or if you feel brave, locate the alias in the registry and delete it
>   there.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo\

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error which was coming and dont need to worry about this error, just restart the server and restart the SQL services. This issue comes when there is low disk space issue and system will go into hung state and then the sql services will stop automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Received SQLSTATE 01000 in the following error message below:

> SQL Agent - Jobs Failed: The SQL Agent Job "LiteSpeed Backup Full" has failed with the message "The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User X.  The last step to run was step 1 (Step1).  NOTE: Failed to notify via email. - Executed as user: X. LiteSpeed(R) for SQL Server Version 6.5.0.1460 Copyright 2011 Quest Software, Inc. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 1)  LiteSpeed for SQL Server could not open backup file: (N:\BACKUP2\filename.BAK). The previous system message is the reason for the failure. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 60405).  The step failed."

In my case this was related to permission on drive N following an SQL Server failover on an Active/Passive SQL cluster.

All SQL resources where failed over to the seconary resouce and back to the preferred node following maintenance. When the Quest LiteSpeed job then executed on the preferred node it was clear the previous permissions for SQL server user X had been lost on drive N and SQLSTATE 10100 was reported.

Simply added the permissions again to the backup destination drive and the issue was resolved.

Hope that helps someone.

Windows 2008 Enterprise

SQL Server 2008 Active/Passive cluster.